# How to map a different JSON request to their individual POJOs in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am constructing a micro-service using spring boot and it receives 2 different JSON requests that follow different schemas, like..

```
{
    "field":"value",
    "filed2":"value2"
}
```

and

```
{
   "form_data":[
      {
         "form_key":"field",
         "form_value":"value"
      },
      {
         "form_key":"field2",
         "form_value":"value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I have 2 different classes that implement a common interface. Is it possible to map first JSON schema to first class, and the second one to the second class.

Answer (score 0):

you can,

1. use two different url mappings.  e.g. /request1  /requst2
2. in the parameter, use the object as parameter.